# Identity Server4 - Correlation failed

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

My problem appeared when I updated the environment to .NET 8, before everything worked (for .NET 6)

Error page
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khwyQ.png)

Client configuration

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = configuration["IdentityUrl"];
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ClientId = configuration["ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = configuration["ClientSecret"];
    options.ResponseType = "code";

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters 
    { 
        NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name,
        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
    };
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email);
    options.Scope.Add(AccountConstants.Scopes.All);
    options.Scope.Add(AccountConstants.Scopes.Roles);

    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role);

    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        if (string.Equals(context.Request.Query["X-Requested-With"], "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
            string.Equals(context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"], "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            context.Response.Headers["Location"] = "/Accounts/Account/SignOutNow";
            context.Properties.RedirectUri = $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}";
        }
        else
        {
            context.Properties.RedirectUri = $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{context.Request.PathBase}";
            context.Properties.Items.Add(OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey, context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
            context.ProtocolMessage.State = options.StateDataFormat.Protect(context.Properties);
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Redirect;
            context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.ProtocolMessage.CreateAuthenticationRequestUrl();
        }

        context.HandleResponse();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Identity server configuration

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options => {

    options.IssuerUri = "null";
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Accounts/SignIn";
    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Accounts/SignOut";
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
})
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityServerConfig.Ids)
.AddInMemoryApiScopes(IdentityServerConfig.ApiScopes)
.AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerConfig.Apis)
.AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerConfig.GetClients(configuration))
.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

if (isProduction)
{
    var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
    {
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var credentials = new ClientCredential(configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureKeyVaultClientId"), configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureKeyVaultClientSecret"));
        var authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credentials);
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }));

    builder.AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(client.GetSecretAsync(configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureKeyVaultIdentityServer4Certificate")).Result.Value), configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureKeyVaultIdentityServer4CertificatePassword")));
}
else
{
    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("IsToken", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrl");
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = AccountConstants.ApiNames.All;
    });
```

I tried to look for solutions on the Internet, but most of them pointed to modifications to UseCookiePolicy(), unfortunately it did not help.

My current configuration

```
if (app.Environment.EnvironmentName == EnvironmentConstants.DevelopmentEnvironmentName)
{
    app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
        Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using https both client and server?or it would be blocked by browser. A related issue here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025079/identityserver4-correlation-failed

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I don't use https locally because everything has always worked... I can only add that the services are run on docker. Do you have any other suggestions? maybe I need to change something with the cookie policy?

Comment: I got some ideas for how to troubleshoot and diagnose cookie problems in my blog post here https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

Comment: @ToreNestenius Unfortunately it didn't help. I launched the project again, in .NET 6 and .NET 8 versions, and the entire cookie blocking process is identical in my local environment

Comment: running multiple instances of the services? (containers?)

Comment: @ToreNestenius Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the default settings for cookie options changed with latest versions of .NET. If you're doing the HTTP commutation instead of HTTPS on your local environment, add the following lines to the AddOpenIdConnect

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    if (builder.Environment.EnvironmentName == EnvironmentConstants.DevelopmentEnvironmentName)
    {
        options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple services; then you must configure The Data Protection API to use the same encryption key (key-ring); otherwise, cookies/nonce/state from one instance won't be accepted by the other one.

I recently wrote a blog post about [the Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/) that can give you some insights into the content of the nonce/state parameters.

See [Configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

The alternative is to ensure that the same service instance is used through-out the entire authentication cycle.

Comment: I have Data Protection configurations in each application :(

Comment: do they share the same key? so secrets issued by one service can be decrypted by other services?

Comment: Yes, Everything works without any problems on .NET 6 and in production. I found another log: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.

Comment: I would look at the logs on both IdentityServer and your client (set log level to debug). And also , exactly what HTTP request is failing?

Comment: After many hours of testing and trials, we found that changes in .NET 8 in the authorization area made it unusable. The solution is to update it yourself or just leave it on .NET 6 for some time and switch to something else in the future. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What changes did you encounter that blocked you?

Comment: None for me, only identity server 4 because it itself is no longer supported from 2022